# Angularjs: Update model when radio button selection changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using Angularjs and I have two radio buttons with the same name `access` and different model fields `model.field1` and `model.field2`, so I need to update the model when selection change, initially `model.field1` and `model.field2` are set to `false`, and I want to set the model value to `true` when cheched and `false` when not checked, how can I do that?

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" data-ng-model="model.field1" name="access"><span>R 1</span>
<input type="radio" id="r2" data-ng-model="model.field2" name="access"><span>R 2</span>
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the preferred way to do this is with a single variable, and the value attribute, like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" data-ng-model="model.field1" value="1" name="access"><span>R 1</span>
<input type="radio" id="r2" data-ng-model="model.field1" value="2" name="access"><span>R 2</span>
{{model.field1}}
```

This will set the variable `model.field1` to 1 or 2 depending on which is selected. It is undefined if nothing is selected. Let me know if this will work for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @Dested, I know that way but in this case I have two variables for representing separated attributes in order to give access to users for example: user.readWrite and user.readOnly and a single variable is not so useful for me. Have you any other idea?  Thanks a lot

Comment: The only way I can think off of hand is to set value to "true" in both cases, default them both to false, and use a series of watches on all of the applicable fields to set them to false when any one of them gets set to true... Another option would be to use 0 for readOnly, 1 for readWrite, and to a watch on THAT value, and set the actual variables representing the accessibility appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Dested, Your suggestion was very useful for me. I solved the problem watching the variable value and setting the actual variables appropriately. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set them with a single scope variable and `ng-value` as shown in the Angular docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).

```
<input type="radio" id="r1" ng-model="model.field1" ng-value="1" name="access"><span>R 1</span>
<input type="radio" id="r2" ng-model="model.field1" ng-value="2" name="access"><span>R 2</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @MBielski, I know that way but in this case I have two variables for representing separated attributes in order to give access to users for example: user.readWrite and user.readOnly and a single variable is not so useful for me. Have you any other idea? Thanks a lot